# Javascript: Linked object/list function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

I am trying to return the length of a linked object(list). However, the function I wrote doesn't return anything.

````
let linkedObject = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }

function countDepth(liste, count = 0){
        if (liste == null) return count
        else {
            count ++
            liste = liste.rest
            countDepth(liste, count)
    } 
}

console.log(countDepth(linkedObject))```

expected output:
'3'
actual output:
'undefined'
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the recursive call:

```
return countDepth(liste, count);
```

Also note it can be optimized and made more concise like so:

```
const countDepth = (l, c = 0) => !l ? c : countDepth(l.rest, ++c);
```

Comment: This worked, but you can explain why for future reference?

Comment: Because if the `if` statement isn't fulfilled, there are no returns within that execution of the function, so `undefined` is returned.

Comment: Ohh..I think that makes sense. The first iteration returns the second iteration, which returns the third and so on...all the way to the actual answer. Without the second return statement, this chain would be broken and the actual answer would be left abandoned.